# How to load separately submodules included in a project?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say i have a project in a git repository with two submodule A and B. I clone my project and then to load the modules i have to do

```
 git submodule init
 git submodule update
```

This will download **all** my module. There's a a way to select only module A or only module B, **WITHOUT** having to change submodules settings on the main project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) commands (`init` and `update`) can take a `<path>...` as a parameter.

So you can try:

```
git submodule init -- A
git submodule update -- A

git submodule init -- B
git submodule update -- B
```

Comment: Good idea. Accordingly to the official documentatio, must be so for it says "Optional <path> arguments limit which submodules will be initialized." but i am not really sure what i must put in <path>

Comment: Inside main git directory there's an hidden file containing informations about the submodules linked to the project. Every submodule has a 'path = xxx' line. <path> must be the content of that line. Btw it seems to me the name of the directory that contains the submodule. Thank you very much @VonC for pointing it out